# Open API spec equivalent for non HTTP protocols like AMQP

Tags: asynchronous, swagger, amqp, openapi

We use Open API specifications (OAS) for HTTP APIs. We use these in our microservice/applications to generate a Swagger UI, but it's also great for documentation and collaboration.

Some internal messaging is also done asynchronously via a message broker (RabbitMQ/AMQP). Is there something that other people/companies use to document async messages operations? It would be nice to just hand integration teams something like an OAS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm currently working with a team who are evaluating [Async API](https://www.asyncapi.com/) for describing services that use messaging over AMQP and other similar protocols. It sounds like it might address some of your needs?